# Can a project using Crashlytics have a GoogleService-Info.plist file renamed to something else?

Tags: xcode, crashlytics

I have a project with one target.

This target has a few schemes for different purposes and each scheme has their own GoogleService-Info.plist.

One of them needs 2x GoogleService-Info.plist for 2x different Firebase clouds. I need to change the default name to be able to differentiate them when selecting the right one in AppDelegate.

I have a script that makes sure to add the right plist file(s) in the package.

Everything is working fine (Firestore, Storage, Functions, etc) until I added Firebase Crashlytics. Now, when compiling, I get the "Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment" error.

I discovered that I can't have a different name for GoogleService-Info.plist to be able to compile properly.

Is it something known? Is there a work around?